# Count the number of lines having more than N words using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I am having a sample file `sample.txt` having the contents as below:

```
this is me
hello
my name is x
awk tutorials
unable to get this right
```

I want to count the number of lines with more than N words. Let's consider `N=3`

Hence, the desired output is `2` (3rd line and 5th line).

I have tried the below code:

`cat sample.txt | awk 'BEGIN{count=0}{"NF>3" then count++} END{print count}'`

My output is always `5` (which is the number of lines in the file; the output remains the same even when N is changed from 3 to 8, indicating that the condition is always True).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
 awk -v num="3" 'NF>num{count++} END{print count}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'NF>3{count++} END{print count}'  Input_file
```

***Problem with OP's code attempt:***

- OP's method of condition `"NF>3" then count++` is not right.
- In spite of looking for lines where NF>3 its increasing value of count every time and hence each time output is `5`.